# Incompatible types with Function interface when passing into a function

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class in which a Function interface (*java.util.function.Function*) is passed through the constructor and it seems like I'm almost there but I'm getting an "Incompatible types: Object is not convertible to RequestOptions" error when I actually pass it into the object as a parameter.

The line I'm referring to is:

```
public static final Request testReqAnswers = new Request(SA_URL, 200, answersEndpoint, Requests::postStatusCode, getFunnelAnswersQueries(advisorMatchQueries, funnelResponseValues));
```

Am I passing it incorrectly?

Below are all of the relevant code blocks

```java
    public static boolean CheckStatusCodeRelook(Request request, Object... requestObj) {
        String requestURL = request.environ + request.endpoint + ((requestObj.length > 0) ? requestObj[0].toString() : "");
        StringWriter requestWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintStream requestCapture = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(requestWriter));
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions(requestURL, new RequestLoggingFilter(requestCapture));

        int statusCode = (int) request.serializer.apply(options);
        requestCapture.flush();

        extentReportLog(requestWriter, String.valueOf(statusCode));
        return statusCode == request.statuscode;
    }

    public class Requests extends Base {
        public static int postStatusCode(RequestOptions options) {
            return given()
                    .filter(options.filter)
                    .spec(customRequest)
                    .post(options.requestUrl)
                    .statusCode();
        }
    }

    public class Request<T> {
        int environ;
        int statuscode;
        String endpoint;
        Function<RequestOptions, Integer> serializer;
        //Function<RequestOptions, Object> serializer; This doesn't work but could in theory right?
        Class<?> toBeSerialized;


        public Request(int environ, int statuscode, String endpoint, Function<RequestOptions, Integer> serializer, Class<?> toBeSerialized) {
            this.environ = environ;
            this.statuscode = statuscode;
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
            this.serializer = serializer;
            this.toBeSerialized = toBeSerialized;
        }

    }
    
    public static final Request testReqAnswers = new Request(URL, 200, endpoint, Requests::postStatusCode, getQueries(Queries, Values));
```

Comment: What would be considered a non-raw type of a Function interface? Trying to make it static or setting the Function interface to Function<?,?> doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: It's nothing to do with Function, that's a red herring. Instantiate Request properly and it'll work. Here's a hint `RequestSOMETHING HERE testReqAnswers = new RequestSOMETHING HERE(`